# Render methods issue - React js

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm trying to get value from DefaultOpts.jsx and update the values to  setState in Filters.jsx. But I'm getting error as below :

**setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.**

**Filters.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultOpts from 'DefaultOpts.jsx';

export default class Filters extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);        
        this.state = {
            vOptions : []
        }
        this.handleOptions = this.handleOptions.bind(this)
    }

    handleOptions(params) {
        console.log(params)
        this.setState({
            vOptions : params
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div> 

                <DefaultOpts handleOptions={this.handleOptions.bind(this)} />

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**DefaultOpts.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class DefaultOpts extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {        
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {

    }

    render() {

        var optArray = "";

        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "url-path",
            success: function(data) {
                optArray = data;
            }
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.handleOptions(optArray)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DefaultOpts;
```

I got some answers in stackoverflow but I'm not able to get what's issue in my code. Please suggest me here what's wrong in my code..

Comment: The problem is that you are invoking `handleOptions` in the render method of `DefaultOpts`. This means that that function will be called during render. While you definitely can call a function inside the render, what you cannot do is `setState` during render, which is what `handleOptions` does in the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `this.props.handleOptions` inside the `render` because it will trigger `setState` of the parent component - and you are still inside the rendering process. That's why it complains.

Try to execute this function inside the `componentDidMount` (together with your ajax call)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

1) First and main one that results in the mentioned error is the fact that by calling `handleOptions` in render you are calling setState that in turn starts react life cycle. This is a **really bad practice and always should/can be avoided**.

2) You have one more async call to `$.ajax` in render that does not directly result in updating state but still considered a bad practice.

To conclude - your render function must not result in any app logic being performed, its task is to render results that have already been prepared. Do all heavy/async work in componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate and you will be fine.

Comment: nice, but (1) is a big no-no - not just a "bad practice".

Answer (score -1):

render will execute before didMount... so you are setting the state before it is mounted

anyway move the $.ajax call to didMount, you shouldn't be doing logic things in render()